# where are agrregation pipeline executed/Computed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Are they computed on node js or server or the in the Mongodb server like the RDBMS stored procedures and postgres fuctions work

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation pipleines are executed on mongoDB server/cluster side , but there is stages executed on data nodes , there is stages executed on routing nodes (mongoses).